CSRF token not validated for form with GET method
I'm trying to implement an anti-CSRF token in a dummy flask app with 2 forms in same page.
CSRF token validation is working for POST form (route /change_password) but not for update email form (route /update_email).
Whenever I try intercept the request and remove the token from update email request , it got accepted.
If I do the same for change password form , it got rejected with an "The CSRF session token is missing." error
@app.route('/update_email', methods=['GET'])
def update_email():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    username = session['username']
    new_email = request.form.get('email')
    if new_email:
        users[username]['email'] = new_email
    return redirect(url_for('profile'))

@app.route('/change_password', methods=['POST'])
def change_password():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    username = session['username']
    new_password = request.form.get('new_password')
    if new_password:
        users[username]['password'] = new_password
        return "Password changed successfully", 200
    return "New password is required", 400

html:
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome, {{ username }}!</h1>
        <p>Your email: {{ email }}</p>
        
        <h2>Update Email</h2>
        <form method="GET" action="{{ url_for('update_email') }}">
        
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="New Email" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Update Email">
        </form>
        
        <h2>Change Password</h2>
       
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('change_password') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

            <input type="password" name="new_password" placeholder="New Password" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Change Password">
        </form>
        
        <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
    </div>
</body>

Thanks

You have not shown the specifics of your CSRF implementation however CSRF tokens are typically used to prevent malicious code from altering server state. HTTP GET methods must be idempotent by definition and therefore cannot alter server state. There is therefore no benefit in trying to protect a GET request with a CSRF token.
